# Kendo Grid get property value with type in ClientTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I've broken my mind with Kendo library.
I'm trying to do something like that:

```
c.Bound(m => m.Transaction).Title().ClientTemplate(Html.TransactionStateFormat(*currentValue*);
```

And my Html helper below:

```
    public static string TransactionStateFormat(this HtmlHelper helper, TransactionState value)
    {
        string result;
        switch (value)
        {
            case TransactionState.Applied:
                result = "# <img src='/Content/img/checkbox-circle-small-2.png'/> #";
                break;
            case TransactionState.OptOut:
                result = "# <img src='/Content/img/cross-sircle-small.png'/> #";
                break;
            case TransactionState.Undefined:
                result = "# N/A #";
                break;
            default:
                result = "# N/A #";
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The question is how to get current value of `Transaction` to put it in to the html helper method? Or how to make the same thing by another way? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
c.Bound(m => m.Transaction).Title().ClientTemplate("#=TransactionStateFormat(data)#");


public enum TransactionState: int 
{
    Applied = 0,
    OptOut=1,
    Undefined=2
}
```

and you add this javascript function

```
<script>
function TransactionStateFormat(data)
    {
        var result='';
        switch (data.Transaction)
        {
            case 0:
                result = "<img src='/Content/img/checkbox-circle-small-2.png'/>";
                break;
            case 1:
                result = "<img src='/Content/img/cross-sircle-small.png'/>";
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "N/A";
                break;
            default:
                result = "N/A";
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Are you sure the `Template` method doing the same thing as `ClientTemplate`?

Comment: The result of this the text of my enum names: somwhere I have "Applied", somewhere "Undefined" instead of icons from content.

Comment: kindly can you check when you debug, the function is get called? and the value passed was correct?

Comment: I've already checked and no. The `TransactionStateFormat` is never called. Why?

Comment: How to make this function get called?

Comment: you need to solve your issue on client side, i will edit the code

Comment: The problem is that I have 4 more fields for this enum. Not only `Transaction`

Comment: yes you can, since I passed the entire object "data" and when i accessed the Transaction field i wrote, data.Transaction

Comment: I mean another thing. Do you suggest me to write 5 `swich-cases` for every field?

Comment: this is another question not related to your question, you can start new question, if my answer helped you to solve your problem, kindly marked it as answer and upvote it please

Comment: To tell truth that is why I'm asking. If I have only one field I write the code in to the `ClientTemplate` directly. But I'm trying avoid `copy-past`.

Comment: You have to include more details about your problem "question", that is why better to split your problem into different questions to get more accurate answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106471/discussion-between-user3818229-and-hadi-hassan).